# How do i send message alert from server

Tags: sms, messaging

In my application I need to send a sms from server when the user is inserted some data. This should be sent from server to the mobile number. Is there any ways to do this?
I need something like Bank message alert for credit/debit.

Someone can say how to achieve this.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Yeah, you purchase one of the many monitoring products that have this capability.

Comment: I'm using Windows Xp

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, he might be programming something, in which case try StackOverflow buddy.

Answer (score 1):

A popular service for this is [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/). They have an API that you can script into what ever you need with your App right into and send SMSs to your heart's content.